# Simplest way and example to define angular directive using typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to learn angular using typescript. Where i am stuck is, trying to define an angular directive using typescript. I know how to implement using just angular i.e angular.directive("xyz", function()....). But I am not able to define it using typescript classes. I looked up for some examples to do it on stackoverflow but the codes were too complex for me to understand and they were task specific. I have some code like:

```
module MyDirectives {
    var app = ClassProject.getModule();

    class MyName{
        public restrict: string = 'E';
        public scope = {
            name: '@',
            age: '='
        };

        public template: string = '<div>{{ name }} : {{ age }}</div>';


        static factory():any {
            const direct: any = new MyName();
            return direct;
        }
    }
    app.directive("myName", MyName.factory());
}
```

My html was

```
<div>
<my-name name="loki" age="age"></my-name>
</div>
```

(age being a scope variable)
But I got errors and no output was displayed on html page whatsoever.

I found a way around it by defining the variable as a function i.e

```
module MyDirectives {
    var app = ClassProject.getModule();

    export function myname(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope: {
                name: '@',
                age: '='
            },
            template: '<div>{{ name }} : {{ age }}</div>',
        }
    }

    app.directive('myName', myname);
}
```

The second example works(that used function) but I cant get it to execute properly using the class.

Also please could you tell me if it is okay to implement the directive using function or nothing at all and just define it using angular.directive() in a typescript project.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

directive angularjs required a function. If you want to use directive with typescript class, you need to implement a function Factory for return instance of your class. Look this exemple:

```
Module Directive{
 class myDirectiveCtrl {

        private name: string;
        private items: Array<string>;
        private $q: ng.IQService;
        static $inject = ['$scope','$window','$q'];

        constructor($scope: ImyDirectiveScope, $window) {
            this.name = $scope.name;
            this.items = ['salut', 'hello', 'hi', 'good morning'];
        }

        clickMe = ():void => {
            console.log('dssff');
            this.items.push('yo');
        }

    }
    export interface ImyDirectiveScope {
        name: string
    }

        export class myDirective implements ng.IDirective {
                 restrict = 'E';
                 template = '<div><h1>{{vm.name}}</h1><div ng-repeat="i track by $index in vm.items">{{i}}</div><hr/><button type="button" ng-click="vm.clickMe()">Click Me</button></div>';
                 replace = true;
                 scope = {
                     name: '@'
                 };
                 controller = myDirectiveCtrl;
                 controllerAs = 'vm';

                 link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes, controller: myDirectiveCtrl) => {

                 };

                 constructor() { };
                 static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
                     var directive = () => new myDirective();
                     return directive;
                 }

             }

    app.directive('myDirective',Directive.myDirective.factory());
}
```